# ArrayAdapter messed up the contents of the ListView when notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am developing an android app with a ListView/ArrayAdapter combo with the items being dynamically added when it receives a broadcast from another service.

Here is the initial setup:

```
postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.item, posts);

ListView list = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

list.setAdapter(postAdapter);
```

There are some elements inside the list initially (stored inside posts).

The initial render of the listView from the adapter works perfectly.

However, when a broadcast is received from another service problem occurs.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        String title= intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String content= intent.getStringExtra("content");
        String senderDesc= intent.getStringExtra("senderDesc");
        String receiverDesc= intent.getStringExtra("receiverDesc");

        Post newPost = new Post(title, content, senderDesc, receiverDesc);

        posts.add(newPost);

        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

At first, when the first 2 element is added, the listView still looks fine.

Until the listView is added to about 7 elements, then the next element is no longer rendered as the content of the element in question but the content of a previous element.

For example(pseudo for simplicity):

Below is the initial list:
1
2
3

And when the 4th, and 5th post is added, then the listView looks like:
1
2
3
4
5
as expected,

However, when the 6th and sometimes 7th item is added, then it will look like this
1
2
3
4
5
1
2 ...

Below is my custom PostAdapter function:

public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    int resource;

```
public PostAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Post> posts) {
    super(context, resource, posts);
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Setting up postView
    RelativeLayout postView;

    Post post = getItem(position);

    String titleString = post.getTitle();
    String contentString = post.getContent();
    String senderDescString = post.getSenderDesc();
    String receiverDescString = post.getReceiverDesc(); 

    if(convertView == null) {

        postView = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;

        li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        li.inflate(resource, postView, true);

        TextView contentView = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.postContent);

        contentView.setText(contentString);

    } else {
        postView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }

    // Check if the post has been previously populated;


    return postView;
}
```

}

I have spend over 10 hours on this and I don't know what is causing the problem.

If expert can point it out to me I really appreciate.

Thank you,
Dennis

Comment: What is your getItem function, I recommend keeping a Posts[] array / arraylist of posts in your adapter class and provide public function in adapter class to add data. AddPost(Post post) { posts.add(post)}

Comment: getItem function gets the post from the list I suppose. I think its a build in function.

Comment: yes its adapter function but are u overriding it if not use the above method , I dont think u need to use relative layout, ifonly displaying text use only textview then u also do not require to user convert view pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think View-reused make this happen, put the following method below getView() method comment, it will works. BTW, you should use ViewHolder pattern in AdapterView if you have a lot of items to display

> TextView contentView = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.postContent);
>
> contentView.setText(contentString);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where exactly should I put this? Should I wrap it inside another function and put it below getView?

Comment: no, you don't have to. put them below this comment: // Check if the post has been previously populated;

Comment: Thanks so much!. I solved the problem. Btw, how would I use a ViewHOlder pattern in this case?

Comment: store the views in an object, such as instance of ViewHolder class, then set it as a tag of convertView when convertView is null, so that you can decrease the findViewById() method calls, more detail: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the else part when convertView is not null, do 
else {
        postView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
setText(contentString);
    }